# Missing thread names when monitoring

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I've gone right through my code ensuring that each thread has a name set (either by name= when setting up the thread, or by self.name= from within the thread's class), as I need to find out which threads are still running (I'm therefore enumerating them every minute and printing the results to stdout).

However, whilst some are showing up nicely:

```
<UpdateTimes(Updatetimes0, started daemon -1333515456)>
```

Other's are just showing up like so:

```
<_Worker(Thread-4, started daemon -1363682496)>
```

Where should I be looking for these threads to name them... or is there a better way of monitoring running threads at runtime?

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the `name` during initialization? The pattern you are showing for the other threads looks like what you get if name evaluates to False in `self.__name = str(name or _newname())`. What does the code for `_Worker` look like?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not really sure what the _Worker threads are, so not sure if I have set name for them! I've no idea where 'worker' is coming from, it's not my code...  I'm guessing it must be Kivy (hum, which I meant to tag this with, oops, sorry!)